# creating a constructor for file creation

Tags: java, file, constructor

I am writing a program based on file. My code looks something like this,

```
   public class clazz {
    void somemethod() {
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
        // some code at final
        write(buf);
    }

    void write(StringBuffer buffer) {
        FileWriter f = new FileWriter(fileName);
        BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(f);
        // implemented write, flush, close
    }
}
```

when I call `somemethod` method, the file gets open every time. I need to open the file once using constructor and reuse the BufferedWriter. Help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like something that your adviser told you to do and you have no clue.

1. Make BufferedWriter a instance variable
2. Initialize it in your constructor.